# Getting more out of Request.HttpContext.User.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity, claims, asp.net-core-identity

When using MVC Core Identity, I am wondering if it is possible to get more information out of `Request.HttpContext.User.Identity`?

Currently, when I look at available, all it gives me back is `Name`, `AuthenticationType`, and `IsAuthenticated`.

What I would like to do for example is also get the Email address as well.

Comment: read up on [`ClaimsPrincipal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx) and related classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get User Manager From Owin Context
                var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager>();
                var user = userManager.FindById(Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.GetUserId()));
```

Using the above codes, it will return the full user object. I believe that solves your problem?

Comment: Right, but my understanding is that you can avoid all that processing if you just use claims.